# Session is always empty after redirect

Tags: laravel

I'm using this code to redirect to route with flashed session:

```
return redirect()->route('test.createInstitution')->with([
    'gates_response' => $response
]);
```

And I'm trying to get this flashed session in controller like this:

```
$response = session('gates_response');
```

But I always get null, no matter what. Even tried not flashed session (With `session(['gates_response' => $response]);`) but same...

If I use in web.php I could access session successfully.

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
    ...
    return redirect()->route('test.createInstitution')->with([
        'gates_response' => $response
    ]);
});
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/test/register/{institution?}', 'test@redirect')->name('test.register');
Route::post('/test/callback/{institution?}', 'test@callback')->name('test.callback');
Route::get('/test/create-institution', 'test@createInstitution')->name('test.createInstitution');
Route::post('/test/store-institution', 'test@storeInstitution')->name('test.storeInstitution');
```

Any ideas how to fix that? Thanks for answers in advance!

P.S Redirect method is called from /test/callback/institution URI

Comment: Sorry, what did you set in laravel settings as session storage? In case of redis or another session storage, pls check is redis is enabled :)

Comment: session driver is file

Comment: check the permissions of storage/framework/sessions folder, or try to change the session driver to array

Answer (score 0):

first check whether session has data or not..

```
 if(Session::has('gates_response'))
 {
   $session_data = Session::get('gates_response');
 }
```

change the redirect code.No need for the array brackets `[`

```
 Session::put('gates_response',$response);
 Session::save();
 return redirect()->route('evartai.createInstitution');
```

Comment: As I mentioned i always get null

Comment: Just check whether you have any data in `$response` variable

Comment: try to change the redirect statement and check

Comment: Changed and still get null

Comment: Then before you redirect, put the value in to the session using `Session::put('gates_response',$response)` and simply redirect `return redirect()->route('evartai.createInstitution')`

Comment: Yeah.. tried this before. After redirect to route session resets and is null

Comment: If it is not working, change `session.php` in config folder as follows.`cookie => laravel_session`, 
to
`cookie => myapp_session`,

Comment: Finally found the solution! Needed to change to 'same_site' => null, instead of 'same_site' => 'strict', but question is it safe to use null instead of strict?

Comment: In the strict mode, the cookie is withheld with any cross-site usage. Even when the user follows a link to another website the cookie is not sent.

Comment: So you can use it.